# Observed Maximum Frequency Not Expected For Given Sample Rate

Tags: downsampling

I'm downsampling a given .wav from 44100 to 22050 samples/second. When I play it back I'm looking at the signal with an EQ, and I would expect that I wouldn't see any content above ~11k. However, I see lots of high frequency content all the way up to ~40k.

How is this possible? Is this a sign that I'm downsampling incorrectly?

Edit:
The issue seems to be that I'm upsampling after downsampling to return the sample to it's original length. If I don't do that then the observed frequency content is as expected.

Comment: Can you share your downsampling code? You're correct, you shouldn't see content above ~11k (at least not significant content), and this might be indication of a bad down-sampling routine.

Comment: There's very little code that isn't just from a library. However, I think the issue is that I'm upsampling after downsampling to return the sample to it's original length. If I play back the sample without upsampling it, the EQ shows the frequency content stopping where expected.

Funny though, because I was comparing against another downsampling effects plugin and it was producing the sample results, so it must also be doing the same thing.

Comment: proper interpolation is the combination of upsampling and filtering, perhaps the issue is in the interpolation filter.

Comment: How are you up-sampling then?

Comment: Just resampling with sinc interpolation.